# FFmpeg – Keep original video orientation

Tags: video, ffmpeg, rotate

I'm converting 3gp video to mp4 format and that is working. But I have one issue: original video orientation is not kept.

I know about *rotate, flip* and other commands, but I'm converting video programmatically and in runtime I don't know the original video rotation value.

Does `ffmpeg` have a flag to keep the original video rotation value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just updated my ffmpeg tool version from 0.x.x, to 2.4.2. New version don't has this issue.